# Error creating Neo4j composite index

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to create a composite index as documented in http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/#create-a-composite-index

This is what I tried.

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(firstname, surname)
```

however I get the error
Invalid input ',': expected an identifier character, whitespace or ')' (line 1, column 34 (offset: 33))
"CREATE INDEX ON :Person(firstname, surname)"

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Composite indexes are only available in Neo4j 3.2 which has been released a couple of days ago, make sure you run this version.